# Taking a screen shot from the console window to check if google tag manager has fired or not

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, phantomjs, google-tag-manager

To check if the google tag manager has fired or not I usually go to the web console and take a look at the output which shows if GTM has fired or not. I first need to go to google tag manager preview view, and then put in the url (which I need to check for gtm) in the address bar and later have a look at the web console which says if the gtm for that particular URL has got fired or not. Since this is quite time taking, I would like to automate this process by taking a snapshot of the output in the web console. Could any body please advice as to how this can be done. I thought of doing it via Phantom JS, but then wasn't sure how, because there are two things involved - (1) First, we need to go to google tag manager preview view and then key in the URL in the address bar  (2) I need the snapshot of the output in the console window.

Please advice how I can go about doing this and if automation is actually possible.

Answer (score 0):

try Google Tag Assistant, from the Chrome App Store. It's a decent tool which helps a lot with troubleshooting and validating Google tags such as Adwords, Tag Manager, Analytics, etc.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en

It offers tips how to fix issues and verifies when tags fire correctly.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use selenium browser testing